# c# DataSet.Fill dreadful performance issues with Firebird 2.5

Tags: c#, performance, firebird, firebird2.5, dataadapter

**REMARK** I completely rewrite the question as while exploring options and getting insights, I realized the origin of my problem was not at all what I thought.

I use Firebird as a database engine and the standard .Net provider (v.5.11.0) to fetch data using following code:

```
// myBlob1 is BLOB SUB_TYPE 1 (text field) with some empty, but some
// VERY long stuff (xml-content) which exceeds VARCHAR(32765), but I removed
// those before performing my tests!!!
var tick = Stopwatch.StartNew();
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();      
DbLive.Open();
FbCommand command = new FbCommand("SELECT myBlob FROM MY_TABLE", DbLive);
try {
    dataTable.BeginLoadData();
    FbDataAdapter fda = new FbDataAdapter(command);
    fda.Fill(dataTable);
    dataTable.EndLoadData();
}
command.Dispose();
DbLive.Close();
tick.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Execution time: " + tick.ElapsedMilliseconds + " [ms]");
```

I am fetching about 30k rows with, in total, about 16Mb of data (according to database workbench's statistics) but only 20k rows with non-null data.

So I go fetching the whole thing using naive approach, then I used the `cast (VARCHAR(8192))` approach (note that I removed all rows with > 8192 characters before doing the tests). Now, here are the results :

```
// Obtained when loading data over wifi, with a bandwidth of about 100Mbps)
// the performance on local machine did not make a big difference!)
No casting:  73287.0788 ms
With casting: 2360.2244 ms
```

There really is something bad going on with `Blobs` here. I tested performance using Firebird 3 and compression, but results weren't much better (a very small improvement, but difference is still of the same order of magnitude).

To the point:
1. Can I expect an improvement if I use another provider (e.g. `www.ibprovider.com` as suggested, but I was not able to test it)
2. Is this a known issue on other database engines, or is there hope to get improvements by changing to another engine?

Comment: Well, we know we are not looking at the real code because the snippet will always throw an exception. So what don't we know that you should have told us?

Comment: My bad  got lost with formatting... The throw should of course be in brackets...

Comment: 1) You show none of SQL, neither query itself, nor the table definitions (SQL SCHEMA of the table). How then can anyone reason about it? 2) are you sure that FlameRobin did fetched ALL the rows, not only doazen or two tops records? There is one thing to START executing query, and another thing to COMPLETE it

Comment: This user posted some more insights on this issue in another question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46680888/firebird-net-performance-issues-with-blobs

Comment: Flamerobin by default doesn't fetch all rows, it will only fetch a few pages, and flamerobin will not fetch blobs by default (only on-demand). The same probably applies to Database Workbench.

Comment: BLOBs are stored out of the table and do require additional network round-trip. So when in network speed bottlenecked situation it indeed might decrease the throughput 2-3 times. Are you blobs really big ? You can try to un-blob them `select ... cast (BlobField as VarChar(1024)) ... from ....` Note however, that total row size is limited with 32 KBytes on Firebird, and that UTF-8 encoded strings/blobs take 4 bytes per letter

Comment: u still neither showed SQL Schema for the table, nor commented on BLOB-less query approach. I can only say that `// iterate throw each without doing anything` B method does NOT fetch BLOBs, so is incorrect to compete. You really should set all the data. So is Dapper<T> is T record does not include some BLOB filed

Comment: `da.Fill(resultTable);` - maybe it is resultTable that is the slow one there. Try to set it with the same options the adapters uses and populate it in the B method. Lastly, you said nothing about `if you think it is provider bug, you can probably test with another provider like www.ibprovider.com `

Comment: `I even tried with Firebird 3 using compression, without significant improvement` - and there could not be. The immediate cause of your slowdown is not the network throughput (sustained speed), your problem is latency, google what "network roundtrip" is. Every BLOB is another separate request to the server and a separate response (if BLOBs are short; if BLOBs are long and occupy several segments - then same for each segment of every BLOB  in every row)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel does wire protocol in fb3/fb4 still require additional requests for BLOBs? I wish there could be some "row batch streaming" option, when the demanded BLOBs got appended to the row packet being asked for. That way access libraries could cache, for example, pre-fetching 10 rows with blobs and 30 next rows w/o BLOBs and other rows when cached rows would be actually read.

Comment: @Arioch'The No, blobs still need to be requested separately in FB3, and I'm not aware of changes in FB 4 in this regard.

Comment: `FbDataAdapter` will load actual data which means the blob data will be fetched, while `FbDataReader` will not load data unless you explicitly request the column value, so it will never ask for the blob data in your code example (as it doesn't do anything).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel another potential day saver could be making protocol asynchronous, like HTTP 1.1 when pipelining - so that client can issue several requests to which server would send responses when ready, that way the client would have been able to request BLOBs and keep fetching next rows or previously requested BLOBs while the last BLOB roundtrips is going through.....

Answer (score 1):

I got a bit confused about many things with the above, so let me clarify some insights:

1. `FbDataReader` and the `Dapper` approaches did, in fact, NOT load the blob fields, so performance was indeed irrelevant;
2. Using the `CAST` to `VARCHAR(4096)` did show significant performance improvements (note that here, I tested the text-blob's content to fully match, which did work):

   DataTable no cast: 73287.0788 ms

   FbDataReader cast:  2224.1387 ms

   DataTable cast:     2360.2244 ms

I even tried with Firebird 3 using compression, without significant improvement. So it is indeed the fact I use `BLOB` instead of large `VARCHAR` that caused the problem.

Note that I did not succeed in testing with another provider.

Bottom line : using `BLOB SUBTYPE 1` kills my performance here, I should use `VARCHAR` instead.

Comment: Clarifying things is good. Clarifying things in wrong places is bad  and confusing. Please, 1) edit your QUESTION and add them new details there, 2) add the comment under the Q notifying people you updated the Q with more details, 3) delete this "answer" because it is not an answer at all

Comment: I edited your answer and removed the parts that should be considered follow-up questions. Note that those follow-up questions might be better suited for the firebird-devel or firebird-net-provider mailing lists than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered a similar performance issue when using Firebird 3 embedded and FBDataAdapter to read BLOB text fields. The query itself didn't seem to be the problem - it executed pretty quickly in Flamerobin. Than I noticed that Visual Studio was reporting a long series of:

> Microsoft C++ exception: Firebird::status_exception at memory location
>   0x0000007DD010B920

although these exceptions are not seen by the calling .Net application.

It turned out that much of the slowdown was apparently due to the Visual Studio IDE trying to handle the many exceptions that are raised. There's a "quiet" exception raised for every BLOB field that is read. This occurs when reading "segments" of the BLOB via `isc_get_segment`, which is called repeatedly until all segements have been read. `isc_get_segement` apparently throws an exception behind the scenes when the end of data is encountered.

When I'm running under the Visual Studio IDE and debugger, this slows things way down, but performance is reasonable if I run the application on its own.