# Firebird .net performance issues with blobs

Tags: .net, performance, blob, firebird

I have a huge performance issue with firebird in my .net app, as discussed here:

[c# DataSet.Fill dreadful performance issues with Firebird 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46670733/c-sharp-dataset-fill-dreadful-performance-issues-with-firebird-2-5)

I found that I was actually reading a blob text field in the query. I've read the .net provider was possibly bugged (indeed, the query runs fine with other db tools that fetch the whole thing).

Is there an alternative? How can I reach decent performance also over the network? I mean I can live with something under 10s, but 80s for 30k records? That's more than 0.5s per record...! And most records have ‘null’ values!

Comment: BLOBs are stored out of the table and do require additional network round-trip. So when in network speed bottlenecked situation it indeed might decrease the throughput 2-3 times. Are you blobs really big ? You can try to un-blob them `select ... cast (BlobField as VarChar(1024)) ... from ...`. Note however, that total row size is limited with 32 KBytes on Firebird, and that UTF-8 encoded strings/blobs take 4 bytes per letter.

Comment: Also, I think it was not smart to make two separate questions on it. Better fix your old question to have all the thoughts and details from this one.

Comment: Also, if you think it is provider bug, you can probably test with another provider like www.ibprovider.com

Comment: I have closed this as duplicate of the other question. I suggest you edit that question, to add more information there.